# What verbs require an impersonal “es” object?

Tags: verb, expletiva

I’ve noticed that some verbs require an *es* as an object to be correct:

> Ich lasse dich es wissen. (es wissen)

while other verbs do not:

> Ich habe vor, nach Hause zu gehen. (not *Ich habe es vor,...*)

How do you know which verbs require or when it's needed to use an *es* in this manner, and when it's not.

Comment: Good question, not so lucky examples... "Ich lasse dich wissen, wann ich komme" "Ich habe es vor." Those two do not behave any differently.

Comment: You really should chose different examples. I think people do not understand that you are trying to ask lists for "Ich genieße es, zu..." (es =good,optional) and "Ich versuche, zu... " (es = wrong).

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, *es* is used as a placeholder for the actual object. It is rather not used without a proper context:

> Sagst du mir Bescheid, wenn eine Entscheidung getroffen wurde?
>   Ich lasse *es* dich wissen. --> Ich lasse dich wissen, wenn eine Entscheidung getroffen wurde.

The same applies to the second example:

> Gehst du gleich nach Hause?
>   Ich habe *es* vor. --> Ich habe vor, gleich nach Hause zu gehen.

Usually, you shorten it even further to

> Habe ich vor.

The context reference is implicit, but would normally need to be present.

Comment: I agree. It is the same as with contact clauses in the English language: At times you can omit a word, but it is never wrong to put it there.
Also it sounds colloquial to omit it.

Comment: Bonus question: What about "Es regnet"? ;)

Comment: I'd daresay this originates from _Wasser regnet vom Himmel_, which is then shortened to _Es regnet_ --> Das Wasser

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question. See my comment at the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I think **it depends on the verb.**

> Ich lasse dich es wissen

**`wissen`** requires *almost always* an object. In German you cannot let somebody know without actually saying *what*. Sometimes it can be omitted / is given implicitly

> Weißt du, ...ich hatte mal ein ähnliches Erlebnis.
>   Er hat gestern angerufen. - Ich weiß. / Weiß ich. / Das weiß ich.
>   Wie Sie wissen, haben wir einen neuen Angestellten.

In the other example you'd either you `es` *or* the subclause

> Ich habe vor, **nach Hause zu gehen**.
>   *OR*
>   Ich habe **es** vor.

**`Es`** substitutes the subclause so you cannot put both together in one sentence.

Comment: I think the original question is precisely when it's possible to put both together and when not, since undoubtedly in some case they can go together: "ich verdiene es, mehr Geld zu bekommen"